# or Nested List - Vuetify

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to create nested list with more than three levels of nesting. When I put children object of items inside child item in v-list it doesn't display anything.

Is is even possible to create such nested list in vuetify? If not, what solution could be to this problem?

```
<div>
  <v-list v-for="(powerPlant, i) in powerPlants" :key="i">
    <v-list-group
      prepend-icon="fas fa-bolt"
      value=""
     >

      <v-list-tile slot="activator">
        <v-list-tile-title>{{powerPlant.name}}</v-list-tile-title>
      </v-list-tile>

      <v-list-group
        no-action
        sub-group
        value="true"
        v-for="(generator, i) in generators" :key="i"
      >
        <v-list-tile slot="activator">
          <v-list-tile-title>{{generator.name}}</v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile>

        <v-list-tile
          v-for="(option, i) in options"
          :key="i"
        >
          <v-list-tile-title v-text="option[0]"></v-list-tile-title>
          <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-icon v-text="option[1]"></v-icon>
          </v-list-tile-action>
        </v-list-tile>
      </v-list-group>
    </v-list-group>
   </v-list>
  </div>
```

If there is another way to make big nested list using Vue.js without using jQuery I would like to learn to.

Sorry for not explain well. In this way a have posted a can reach 3 levels of list, but i cant go further like four or five levels.

Comment: Your code looks like it should work, see the example here: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/navigation-drawers#example-nested

Are you sure that `option` has content? Try manually typing in values first to get it working.

Comment: I'm sorry it's working, but what I'm saying is that a can't put another subsection on the list like. 1, 1-1, 1-1-1, 1-1-1-1

Comment: Is the sub-sub-section a direct child of the previous `v-list-group`?

Answer (score 13):

I solved this by nesting v-list like this:

```
<v-list>
    <v-list-group v-for='node in nodes' v-model='node.active'>
        <v-list-tile slot='activator' @click=''>
            <v-list-tile-title>{{node.text}}</v-list-tile-title>
        </v-list-tile>
        <v-list class='py-0 pl-1'>
            <v-list-group v-for='child in node.children' v-model='child.active'>
                <v-list-tile slot='activator' @click=''>
                    <v-list-tile-title>{{child.text}}</v-list-tile-title>
                </v-list-tile>
                <v-list class='py-0 pl-2' v-for='grandchild in child.children'>
                    <v-list-tile>
                        <v-list-tile-title>{{grandchild.text}}</v-list-tile-title>
                    </v-list-tile>
                </v-list>
            </v-list-group>
        </v-list>
    </v-list-group>
</v-list>
```

This can go arbitrarily deep. In fact, I needed an infinitely nesting list so I created this simple recursive component:

```
<template>
    <v-list>
        <template v-for='node in nodes'>
            <v-list-group v-if='node.children && node.children.length' v-model='node.active'>
                <v-list-tile @click='' slot='activator'>
                    <v-list-tile-title>{{node.text}}</v-list-tile-title>
                </v-list-tile>
                <node-list class='py-0 pl-3' :nodes='node.children'/>
            </v-list-group>
            <v-list-tile @click='' v-else>
                <v-list-tile-title>{{node.text}}</v-list-tile-title>
            </v-list-tile>
        </template>
    </v-list>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'node-list',
    props: ['nodes'],
}
</script>
```

Comment: awesome thanks, didn't knew i could encapsulate stuff in template